# Typescript gives object might be null error while passing object to function inside promise.then

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, promise

The following is the code from a request controller function.

**Objective**
I wanted to create different types of notifications depending upon the which paths are modified.

```js
let farmerToUpdate = await FarmerModel.findById(farmerId)
  if (!farmerToUpdate) throw new controllerError('Farmer you want to update is deleted', 422)

  // farmerToUpdate.set(Object.assign(farmerToUpdate, req.body))
  farmerToUpdate.set(req.body)

  let directModifiedPaths = farmerToUpdate.directModifiedPaths()
  const updatedFarmer = await farmerToUpdate.save()

  if (directModifiedPaths.includes('farmerCode') || directModifiedPaths.includes('centreCode')) {
    // farmerToUpdate is original document and updatedFarmer is document after updating
    createNotification(farmerToUpdate, updatedFarmer, ['farmerCode', 'lakshmiCentreCode'], true, 'Codes Updated').then(
      function () {
        directModifiedPaths = directModifiedPaths.filter(d => d !== 'farmerCode' && d !== 'lakshmiCentreCode')
        if (directModifiedPaths.length) {
          createNotification(farmerToUpdate, updatedFarmer, directModifiedPaths, false, 'Plain').then(res => {})
        }
      },
    )
  }
```

After creating notification of one type when I try to pass same first argument `farmerToUpdate` to the `createNotification` function I get following error

> Argument of type '(Document<unknown, any, Farmer> & Farmer & { _id: ObjectId; }) | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Document<unknown, any, Farmer> & Farmer & { _id: ObjectId; } & { notificationId?: number | undefined; }'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Document<unknown, any, Farmer> & Farmer & { _id: ObjectId; } & { notificationId?: number | undefined; }'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Document<unknown, any, Farmer>'.

If I add check for a valid `farmerToUpdate` it works fine -

```js
farmerToUpdate && createNotification(farmerToUpdate, updatedFarmer, directModifiedPaths, false, 'Plain').then(res => {})
```

I wonder why it not gives the same error for second parameter or third???

Comment: It's strange since if it complains of `farmerToUpdate` possibly being null, it should complain also of the line `farmerToUpdate.save`

Comment: I've added check for `farmerToUpdate`. but regardless IDK why the error. Also when I call that function outside the `.then` then it works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

The type of `farmerToUpdate` is nullable, but `if (!farmerToUpdate) throw ...`
makes it non-nullable anymore afterward in the same scope or any descendant scopes. (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html)

But the nested function has it's own scope, and in it the `farmerToUpdate`'s type is still nullable.

Ideally, it's maybe possible for the compiler to determine that `farmerToUpdate` will actually never be null in the nested function, but it is more complex and the compiler just doesn't support that I think.

### update:

the return value of `await FarmerModel.findById(farmerId)` is nullable (in another word: it may return null), and therefor `farmerToUpdate` is nullable (in another word: it may be null).

But return values of `farmerToUpdate.directModifiedPaths()` and `await farmerToUpdate.save()` are non-nullable, and therefor `updatedFarmer` and `directModifiedPaths` are both non-nullable (in another word: they'll never be null).

That's why the compiler only compains `farmerToUpdate`, but not `updatedFarmer` and `directModifiedPaths`.

Actually `farmerToUpdate.directModifiedPaths()` should be `farmerToUpdate!.directModifiedPaths()`. That's because the type of `farmerToUpdate` may be null, but we know it'll never be null in that context, therefor we can treat it as non-nullable. The compiler can do that deduction automatically, so we can eliminate the exclamation mark without error.

Comment: `updatedFarmer` depends upon `farmerToUpdate`, why compiler not checking for other args of the function??

Comment: I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes and we have a check for `formerToUpdate` also. Can you explain more why that check is not valid inside the `.then`.

Comment: @shubham I believe that's just a limitation of the compiler. It doesn't apply the type narrowing accross functions.

Comment: `farmerToUpdate!.directModifiedPaths()` should probably be `farmerToUpdate?.directModifiedPaths()`